# How to create a discord bot without it having it be registered as a bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I recently learned how to create a discord bot, and make it send and read messages in channels and dms. With these bots, it always has the "bot" in blue next to its name. I am wondering if there is any way I could remove that. I use the `discord` module. If it is not possible with the `discord` module, are there any other options I could use to send messages from an account without having bot next to its name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Discord does not allow automated user accounts. Read more [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).

Comment: Alright thanks, I didn't know it was against the rules.